# CRAM on an arm processor?

Tags: ros, cram

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has anyone tried running CRAM on an arm processor? Is it possible? roslisp is supported on ARM but there are multithreading issues with SBCL on arm.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211102/cram-on-an-arm-processor?/) by [rohan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2278/rohan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 358 on 2015-06-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [corb](https://answers.ros.org/users/20674/corb/) on 2015-06-13**:
Two things to keep in mind if you try to build something on ARM:

1. use "make -j1".   This will run with one job and prevent Make from using too much memory if memory is limited.
2. default char type is signed on x86, but unsigned on ARM. (Workaround for GCC -fsigned-char parameter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I got the cram part to build on ARM. I didn't try building knowrob.

The main issue with CRAM running on ARM is that roslisp doesn't support ARM. They depend on SBCL which is available for ARM but the multi threading doesn't work for ARM processor therefore roslisp doesn't work on ARM.

https://github.com/ros/roslisp/issues/14

---

Originally posted by [rohan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2278/rohan/) with karma: 358 on 2015-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/9301/gaya/) on 2015-06-15**:
"I didn't try building knowrob." - I don't see any reason for building a knowledge processing system on a microcontroller that runs ROS.
"multi threading doesn't work for ARM" - Have you built SBCL with `-lpthread` flag?
https://github.com/sbcl/sbcl/blob/master/src/runtime/Config.arm-linux

**Comment by [gaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/9301/gaya/) on 2015-06-15**:
The `-lpthread` thing is just an idea, I'm not an expert in Lisp on ARM business.

**Comment by [rohan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2278/rohan/) on 2015-06-15**:
Yes I tried that it didn't help. You can also try --fancy argument when building SBCL but that also doesn't build SBCL with multithreading.